# Part identification - 5 parts

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Please could someone help me with identifying these parts. I could not find a part number on them. I've tried reverse image searching too - but having no luck. Once I have the part numbers I will work out what sets(s) we purchased and go from there - I just need the part numbers to begin.
Images below.
[image: 5 lego parts]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1: two pieces from sets like [6919](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6919-1) - the sticker is magnetic, and fits on 30213 to make [30213pb01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30213pb01)

2: [an Insectoids torso](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=55117#T=C&C=10) - 973pb0037

3: [an Insectoid head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpx31#T=C&C=10) - 3626bpx31

4: might be [a Harold Potter head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpb0155&idColor=12#T=C&C=12) - 3626bpb0155 from set 4711

5: seems to be [an Insectoid helmet](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30214&idColor=20#T=C&C=20) - 30214

Comment: Great answer. I would suggest linking first piece to exact item (30213pb01)

Comment: Oops, didn't scroll to the Counterparts section. It is done!

Comment: Thankyou @RSchulz, 4 of those pieces were part of a Cosmic Creeper set (6837) which is now completed.